# Establishing variable scope in PHP class?

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

This is a very straightforward question that doesn't appear to be directly addressed at php.com - at least from looking through that section.

In any case, I have a class here with a specific function:

```
class CheckOut extends DB_MySQL{

public $fName;
public $lName;
public $numberOut;
public $p_id;

    /.../

    protected function publisherCheck($lName, $fName)
    {
        $this->lName = $lName;
        $this->fName = $fName;

        //Execute test
        $this->checkConnect();
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT p_id FROM People WHERE lastName = :param1 AND firstName = :param2");
        $stmt->bindParam(':param1', $this->lName);
        $stmt->bindParam(':param2', $this->fName);
        $stmt->execute();

        //Determine value of test
        if($stmt == FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            $p_id = $stmt->fetch();
        }

    }
```

Just ignore the fact that there is no constructor posted with missing functions, etc. They're in this class - just not pertinent to my question.

Will setting $p_id in the last statement affect the variable declared initially in the header of the class? Essentially, will it be global within the class?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, it won't. You *always* need `$this->` to tell PHP you're talking about the class properties, not local variables.

```
// Always assignment of a local variable.
$p_id = $stmt->fetch();

// Always assignment of a class property.
$this->p_id = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: Ha, didn't even catch that even though I did that for every other variable. Well, that answered it as well as fixed a future issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. That's a local variable to your function. If you did `$this->$p_id = 'blah';` then it would affect it. The variable you have defined in your class is a property, so it has to be accessed/altered with `$this->....`, whereas the variable you have in your function, is just a local variable (which you can play with by simply doing `$p_id='....'` ).

So,

```
$this->$p_id = '';//will alter the class property
```

and

```
$p_id = '';//will alter the local var defined/used in the function
```